# Android Studio(Java) Client unable to connect on Android Server

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcpsocket

I have just started learning TCPSocket recently. I hope to write a quiz app online through a socket using Android Studio. However, during the execution of the client, it was unable to connect to the server. I repeatedly checked a lot of data and code, but couldn't find a solution

This is the Server part code I currently have:

```
public class ServerWaitStart extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static GlobalVariable gv;

    private ServerSocket serverSocket;

    TextView currentNum;
    private int count = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_11_server_wait_start);

        gv = (GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext();

        TextView IPaddress = findViewById(R.id.IPaddress);
        gv.IP = getLocalIP(this);
        IPaddress.setText("群組代碼:" + gv.IP);

        currentNum = findViewById(R.id.currentNum);
        serverConnect();
    }

    private ServerThread serverThread;

    public void serverConnect(){
        try {
            serverSocket= new ServerSocket(5050);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        serverThread = new ServerThread();
        serverThread.startServer();
    }

    class ServerThread extends Thread implements Runnable{

        private boolean serverRunning;
        private int count = 1;

        public void startServer(){
            serverRunning = true;
            start();
            System.out.println("startServer execute");
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while(serverRunning){
                    System.out.println("in run");
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("accept!");
                    count++;

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                                dos.writeUTF(count + "\n");
                                // 立即發送
                                dos.flush();
                                currentNum.setText("目前已加入人數" + count);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    if (gv.chooseNum == count){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }//ServerThread
```

This is the Client part code I currently have:

```
public class ClientWaitStart extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GlobalVariable gv;
    private TextView currentNum;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_07_client_wait_start);

        currentNum = findViewById(R.id.currentNum);
        gv = (GlobalVariable)getApplicationContext();
    }

    private Runnable Connection=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("10.0.2.16", 5050);
                System.out.println("client connected");

                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                String waitPeopleNum = dis.readUTF();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        currentNum.setText("目前已加入人數；" + waitPeopleNum);
                    }
                });

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    };
```

Please help and ask me any questions that I left vague. Thank you, Laimo.

Server System.out
`2023-06-02 13:22:19.504  5063-5063  System.out              com.appcompat.app.quiz               I  startServer execute 2023-06-02 13:22:19.505  5063-5315  System.out              com.appcompat.app.quiz               I  in run`

Comment: Can you connect to the server from any computer e. g. with `netcat`?

Comment: @Armali Sorry, I haven't used this before. Can you explain in more detail how to try it?

Comment: `netcat -v 10.0.2.16 5050` or `nc -v 10.0.2.16 5050`

Comment: Where is your server running? Where is your client running? On which devices? Tell your setup else we have to guess what you are trying. And what does it have to do with 'online'?

Comment: `serverConnect()` Dont call it like that. Call it serverListen() as that is what happens. Only a client tries to connect -with the server-.

Comment: @blackapps When opened first, it will enter MainActivity.java, where are two buttons to choose between creating a group or joining a group. I set the server for creating the group.
After clicking the button to create a group, you will enter server.java to set the number of game rounds and number of players. After setting it, you can click the button to start the game, and you will enter serverWaitStart.java (attached server part code), where you will create a serverSocket and accept ()

Comment: At this time, you can use another Android device to open the app, click on the join group button, enter clientJoin.java, enter the server IP you want to connect to, and click the enter group button to enter clientWaitStart.java (attached client part code) for socket=new Socket (IP, 5050) and server connection

It has already fixed the IP as the IP of the Android emulator="10.0.2.16"

Comment: @blackapps Thank you fo your reminder! I will change this call.

Comment: @blackapps I execute everything using the built-in emulator in Android Studio, and the server runs in Pixel_ 3a_ API_ 33 x86_64
The client is based on Pixel 3a API 33.

Online is for the server to provide questions and options for the client to answer in the future. The client's answer will be sent back to the server to confirm whether the answer is correct. If the answer is correct, one point can be added, but I did not write this on this page. This page needs to be connected online first

Comment: The server runs on a Pixel device. And then you seem to have a different server on the internet? And what are you executing on the emulator? What? All makes no sense to me. Cant you stick to two Pixel devices first? One for the server and one as a client? The rest is only confusing.

Comment: @blackapps I really only use two-pixel devices, one for the server and one for a client, and those two-pixel devices are opened by emulators. I don’t have a physical pixel device. 

And there is only one server. The multiple java switches mentioned above are only It's just switching pages

Comment: Very confusing post. So you try to use two emulators for server client communication. Well that will not go. Use two devices to begin with. You are not using two pixel devices. You should never have mentioned pixel.